Estimate the drag caused by wind on a free falling body
I'm trying to solve the following problem for my masters thesis: Estimate the drag caused by wind on a free falling body from H altitude. H is in range of 300-1000 meters.
What would be the best way to calculate the drag caused by the wind ?
Assuming I have wind estimates for each altitdue.
Assuming I have drag coefficents of the body for 0.01-0.99 mach numbers.
Assuming I have duartion of the free fall.
Assuming I have center of pressure and center of gravity.

You simply have to write the equation of motion adding the drag as an opposing force of magnitude $D=½ \rho V² S C_D$ with $C_D=C_D(Re, Ma)$ and $V=\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot{x}$. If you post your try we might be able to find the error

This might turn out to be extremely complicated.  First of all, does the problem start with the body at 0 velocity relative to the ground, or at terminal velocity (instantaneous acceleration of zero), or at some other condition?

Drag caused by wind. Ha!  This would involve drift (horizontal) from drop point.  But it may be solved in a similar manner, either as a vector of relative wind or as the wind vector alone.  If you truly want to go Masters level, you may wish to study propeller disk drag on an air craft.  Is it just the drag equation, or does the accelerated airflow around the prop (airfoil) somehow deflect the oncoming air (from aircraft velocity)?  How does this compare to the drag of a prop that isn't turning?

One complicated bit is that any horizontal wind relative to the object (i.e. any time the object's instantaneous horizontal groundspeed is different from the wind speed at that altitude) will also change the vertical force oposing gravity, even in a situation where the only aerodynamic force components are drag components, not lift components.  (E.g. a non-spinning round ball, or a bomb with fins large enough (in relation to angular inertia) to keep it perfectly "weathervaned" to point directly into the instantaneous relative wind at all times.)

To understand this, visit this Physics SE question, paying special attention to the first paragraph below the itemized list of three items:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/491600/236723.  Now add wind shear into the mix (different wind speeds at different altitudes), and it seems that you will have a very complex problem.

An excellent reference, with an interesting result (because of V$^2$).  We may have Thesis yet, but first ... to the wind tunnel for some data!
